# Bios Password Reset or Force USB Boot?

Tags: boot, usb, bios, passwords

I i have Fujitsu AH550 laptop, i put a password on the bios and i forget the password and since i have a broken cd drive and currently no alternative, i can't use usb boot at all.

I searched for a way to reset the password and came with nothing, i tried even flashing the bios but that didn't work from me too.

I tried searching in the documentation of the bios and here what was written, it's really depressing.

```
Remember your passwords! If you set and
forget your User and Master hard disk
passwords, Fujitsu Computer Systems will
not be able to reset it. You may lose data
and have to replace your system board or
hard disk drive.
```

Is there anyway to change the boot order from windows, and is it possible to force boot from usb, or maybe add a usb boot along the windows mulit booting list, if anybody have any idea i would really be grateful.

Update:

Lately i have tried contacting Fujitsu Support and they told this would cost a charge of 155$ and is covered in warranty, but the thing is when i asked if i have to send my laptop they told that it can be done over the phone. This means that there is maybe a generic or something else.

If anyone know of such thing or have anyother way, it would really be great.

Comment: i think that removing the battery won't reset bios password, because laptops are not like pc, in a pc bios data stored in a NVRAM but laptop is different it's stored in a PROM. i don't know if this goes for all laptops or though.

Comment: Who said anything about removing **only** one battery? Quoted from the answer I referred to: _Plug out all batteries, and the adapter, and remove the RTC battery that supplies power to the CMOS BIOS. After about 10 minutes, the BIOS will be reset... along with the password._

Comment: At this point you have nothing to loose by attempting what @karel suggests. Please let us know if it works.

Comment: No, your laptop is recoverable, but needs a relative highly experienced electric engineering. Your bios chip should be soldered out, reinitialized and soldered back. It required costly machines and a costly engineer. Your hard disk is nearly sure O.K., altough your data is probably lost. If your password wasn't really long, and the coding algorithm isn't really secret, then a dictionary-based crack could help you to recover - in this case you got back everything. But this last is in most cases impossible (because the crypting algorithm isn't known, the fujitsu never gave that out).

Comment: i will do what @karel do this weekend. and as i remember that my password was a number and it was short so if there are software that may crack it other than killcmos please tell me about it. Anyhow i will post as soon as i do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a joke. The best bet would be to force your memory to recall your password. With a bit of effort you'll remember it. And bios doesn't have 3x lock-up.